# AngularJS service not working. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

My module:

```
angular.module("aps",
[
    "ngAnimate", "ngTouch", "ui.grid", "ui.grid.saveState", "ui.grid.selection", "ui.grid.cellNav",
    "ui.grid.resizeColumns", "ui.grid.moveColumns", "ui.grid.pinning", "ui.bootstrap", "ui.grid.autoResize"
]);
```

My service:

```
angular.module("aps")
.service("OrderGridOptions",
    function() {
            return {
                enableFiltering: true,
                flatEntityAccess: true,
                showGridFooter: true,
                fastWatch: true,
                rowTemplate:
                    '<div ng-click="grid.appScope.selectOrder(row)" ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="col.colIndex()" ui-grid-cell></div>',
                columnDefs:
                [
                    { name: "WorkOrderID", width: 100, displayName: "Order ID" },
                    { name: "CustomerID", width: 120, displayName: "Customer ID" },
                    { name: "POSID", width: 100 },
                    { name: "CreateDate", width: 120 },
                    { name: "CreatedBy", width: 120 },
                    { name: "Description", visible: false },
                    { name: "EstimatedFinishDate", visible: false },
                    { name: "EstimatedHours", visible: false },
                    { name: "EstimatedCostLabor", visible: false },
                    { name: "EstimatedCostParts", visible: false },
                    { name: "ActualFinishDate", width: 150 },
                    { name: "ActualCostLabor", visible: false },
                    { name: "ActualCostParts", visible: false },
                    { name: "CheckoutBy", width: 120 },
                    { name: "CheckoutNotes", visible: false }
                ],
                data: []
            };
    });
```

My Controller:

```
angular.module("aps").controller("TechSheetCtl",
[
    "TechSheetFactory", "$scope", "$rootScope", "$http", "$interval", "$modal", "$log", "uiGridConstants", "$q",
    "$filter", "CustomerGridOptions", "OrderGridOptions",
    function(TechSheetFactory,
        $scope,
        $rootScope,
        $http,
        $interval,
        $modal,
        $log,
        uiGridConstants,
        $q,
        $filter,
        CustomerGridOptions,
        OrderGridOptions) {

$scope.testTheService = function() {
    alert("testing service");
    alert(JSON.stringify(OrderGridOptions));
}
```

I attached testTheService to a button. Both alerts appear but the second one is empty. I'm trying not to use $rootScope for passing data among all my controllers and this seemed like the best way to do it except I can't make it work.

And I don't even know if my assumption about passing data is correct. If I modify the service's data array in one controller, will another controller be able to access that array?

What am I missing here?

Comment: don't see anything wrong in the code, it should work.

Comment: The second alert statement is missing a closing banana. Services instances are singletons. Any changes to its contents is seen by all.

Comment: One of the most common problems is a mismatch in the inline array annotation. The arguments of the construction function often don't match the list of strings. I personally avoid inline array annotation because it is tedious and error prone. Automated tools like [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) can be used when minimizing code.

Comment: georgeawg: fixed the paran. It wasn't the issue. I just pasted incomplete code.

Comment: Should I just remove the annotations? I mean, I know that's not the problem but...

Comment: Try using `factory` instead of `service`.

Comment: I thought factories allowed for common functions but not common data.. The scope for ctrlA executing a factory function is different than the scope for ctrlB executing the same function.

Answer (score 0):

I simply started from scratch using the exact same code. I have no idea what I had in the old code but I don't care. It worked this time around.